# PHP foreach row as $var, row name and row number duplicate

Tags: php, mysql

I coded a simple function to loop trough and display all variables in the sql table.
However foreach $row displays the rows two times, 1 time as a row name and 1 time as a row number.

1 : $row['NAME'] Name form

2 : $row[0]' Number form

PHP :

```
<?php

include "condetails.php";
$query = "select * from pagedetails";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  foreach($row as $var => $val) {
    echo "VARNAAM :".$var;
    echo "<br />";
    echo "VALUE".$val;
    echo "<br />";
    echo "<br />";
  }
}

?>
```

OUTPUT :

VARNAAM :0
VALUE1

VARNAAM :id
VALUE1

VARNAAM :1
VALUEdddd

VARNAAM :h1txt
VALUEdddd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's displayed twice because `mysql_fetch_array()` grabs the column name and its number.

If you want just the column names try using `mysql_fetch_assoc()`, keep in mind mysql_* functions are depreciated and you should be using PDO / MySQLi :)

Comment: @r-d-r-b-3 its a pleasure mate!

Answer (score 0):

mysql_fetch_array returns a mixed array with keys as numbers and as column names. You probably want mysql_fetch_assoc(), which only returns the name keys.

Answer (score 0):

From [the manual](https://www.php.net/mysqli_fetch_array):

> mysqli_fetch_array() is an extended version of the mysqli_fetch_row() function. **In addition to storing the data in the numeric indices of the result array, the mysqli_fetch_array() function can also store the data in associative indices, using the field names of the result set as keys.**

What you you're really looking for is [`mysqli_fetch_assoc()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php):

> Returns an associative array that corresponds to the fetched row or NULL if there are no more rows.